# Set-cookie ignored for HTTP response with status 302 in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, google-chrome, redirect, cookies, spring-security

I implement certification through spring security.

If i receive targetUrl and authentication is successful, redirect to that targetUrl and create Cookie with that domain.

However, the Set-Cookie header does not work when testing in the local environment.

### Request

```
Request URL: http://auth.develop.in/login?targetUrl=https://test2.test.develop.in/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

### Response

```
Response Header
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 03 Aug 2019 16:38:06 GMT
Location: https://test2.test.develop.in/
Set-Cookie: JWT=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLpEls; Domain=test.develop.in; Path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

### Code

```
fun setCookie(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, value: String) {
    val cookie = Cookie(cookieName, value)
    cookie.path = getCookiePath(request)
    if (cookieDomain != null) {
        cookie.domain = cookieDomain
    }
    response.addCookie(cookie)
}
```

```
Cookie {Cookie@9383}
name = "JWT"
value = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q~~"
version = 0
comment = null
domain = "test.develop.in"
maxAge = -1
path = "/"
secure = false
httpOnly = false
```

I expected Cookie to be created after being redirected normally.

Is there something I don't understand about Cookie?

If I don't redirect, cookies are created.

Comment: What do you mean by *the Set-Cookie header does not work when testing in the local environment.* Show your request for local enviornment.

Comment: @dur Set-Cookie header set and redirected, but no cookies were created.

Comment: Show your request for local enviornment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Could not create cookies for `test.develop.in` on `auth.develop.in`

Change /etc/hosts domain `auth.develop.in` to `auth.test.develop.in`

Comment: I had the same problem. I confirm that this way it finally worked.